# After Search Expndable Listview do not Expand

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to implement a search function in my code. So far, expandable `ListView` works perfectly, but after my search I cannot get a positive answer.

```
(WordPage.xaml.cs):-

public partial class WordPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Word>Words { get; set; }

        public WordPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            ViewList = new WordModel();
            BindingContext = ViewList;
        }

       private WordModel ViewList { get; set; }

        private void MyList_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            Word word = e.Item as Word;
            WordModel wm = BindingContext as WordModel;
            wm?.ShowOrHiddenWords(word);
        }

        private void MySearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyList.BeginRefresh();
            WordModel wm = BindingContext as WordModel;
               MyList.ItemsSource = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewTextValue) 
                   ? ViewList.Words 
                   : ViewList.Words
                        .Where(i => i.Chg.ToLower()
                        .Contains(e.NewTextValue));
            MyList.EndRefresh(); 
        }
    }

(WordModel.cs):-

public class WordModel
    {
        private Word _oldWord;
        public ObservableCollection<Word> Words { get; set; }
        public WordModel()
        {
            Words = new ObservableCollection<Word>
            {
                new Word{Chg="Abi", EngId="Eng", Eng="Grant Father", HinId="Hinti", Hin=" दादा (Papu Chi)"},
                new Word{Chg="Abou", EngId="Eng", Eng="Father", HinId="Hinti", Hin=" पिता (Pitachi)"},
                new Word{Chg="Boo", EngId="Eng", Eng="Wood", HinId="Hinti", Hin=" लकड़ी (Lakeri)"},
                new Word{Chg="Chaangmei", EngId="Eng", Eng="Great Day", HinId="Hinti", Hin="अच्छा दिन (Nam)"},
                new Word{Chg="Dhonbu", EngId="Eng", Eng="Edge", HinId="Hinti", Hin="धार (Lekna)"},
                new Word{Chg="Eei", EngId="Eng", Eng="Wine", HinId="Hinti", Hin="वाइन (Taru)"},
                new Word{Chg="F", EngId="Eng", Eng="--", HinId="Hinti", Hin="--"},
                new Word{Chg="G", EngId="Eng", Eng="--", HinId="Hindi", Hin="--"},
                new Word{Chg="Hanei",EngId="Eng", Eng="Here", HinId="Hindi", Hin="यहाँ (Yaha)"},
                new Word{Chg="Inn", EngId="Eng", Eng="Machete", HinId="Hindi", Hin="एक प्रकार का कुलहाड़ा (Dao)"},
                new Word{Chg="Jih", EngId="Eng", Eng="Time", HinId="Hindi", Hin="(Wath)"},
                new Word{Chg="Kün", EngId="Eng", Eng="Us", HinId="Hindi", Hin="हमें (Hum)"},
                new Word{Chg="Long", EngId="Eng", Eng="Ship", HinId="Hindi", Hin="समुंद्री जहाज (Naow)"},
                new Word{Chg="Mang", EngId="Eng", Eng="Inside", HinId="Hindi", Hin="के भीतर (Under)"},
                new Word{Chg="Nyen", EngId="Eng", Eng="Name", HinId="Hindi", Hin="नाम (Nam)"},
                new Word{Chg="Olin", EngId="Eng", Eng="Happniss", HinId="Hindi", Hin="ख़ुशी (Kushi)"},
                new Word{Chg="Poon", EngId="Eng", Eng="Seeds", HinId="Hindi", Hin="बीज (--)"},
                new Word{Chg="Q", EngId="Eng", Eng="--", HinId="Hindi", Hin="--"},
                new Word{Chg="Ram", EngId="Eng", Eng="Rum", HinId="Hindi", Hin="--"},
                new Word{Chg="Sanou", EngId="Eng", Eng="sorry", HinId="Hindi", Hin="माफ़ कीजिये (Pachari)"},
                new Word{Chg="Tat", EngId="Eng", Eng="Today", HinId="Hindi", Hin="आज (Aach)"},
                new Word{Chg="U", EngId="Eng", Eng="--", HinId="Hindi", Hin="--"},
                new Word{Chg="Vin", EngId="Eng", Eng="Wine", HinId="Hindi", Hin="--"},
                new Word{Chg="Wan", EngId="Eng", Eng="Fire", HinId="Hindi", Hin="आग (Aak)"},
                new Word{Chg="Xamarin", EngId="Eng", Eng="Xamarin", HinId="Hindi", Hin="--"},
                new Word{Chg="Yao", EngId="Eng", Eng="Leg", HinId="Hindi", Hin="टांग (Pear)"},
                new Word{Chg="Z", EngId="Eng", Eng="--", HinId="Hindi", Hin="--"},
                new Word{Chg="Ühei", EngId="Eng", Eng="Hello", HinId="Hindi", Hin="(Namasti)"},
            };
        }

        public void ShowOrHiddenWords(Word word)
        {
            if(_oldWord == word)
            {
                word.IsVisible = !word.IsVisible;
                UpDateWords(word);
            }
            else
            {
                if(_oldWord!=null)
                {
                    _oldWord.IsVisible = false;
                    UpDateWords(_oldWord);
                }
                word.IsVisible = true;
                UpDateWords(word);
            }
            _oldWord = word;
        }

        private void UpDateWords(Word word)
        {
            int Index = Words.IndexOf(word);
            Words.Remove(word);
            Words.Insert(Index, word);
        }
    }

(WordPage.xaml):-

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:WordModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <Grid BackgroundColor="Gray" Margin="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <SearchBar x:Name="MySearch"
                   Text="{Binding Word}"
                   Margin="2,2,2,0"
                   CancelButtonColor="White"
                   Placeholder="Search"
                   PlaceholderColor="White"
                   TextChanged="MySearch_TextChanged"/>

        <ListView Margin="2,0,2,2"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      x:Name="MyList"
                      BackgroundColor="White"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Words}"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      ItemTapped="MyList_ItemTapped">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="5">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Chg}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Black"/>

                            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" BackgroundColor="DarkGreen" Margin="2">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Label Text="{Binding EngId}"
                                               WidthRequest="110"
                                           Margin="2"
                                           FontSize="5"
                                           Font="Italic"
                                           TextColor="LightBlue"/>

                                    <Label 
                                            Text="{Binding Eng}"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            WidthRequest="110"  
                                            FontSize="15"  
                                            TextColor="White"/>
                                </Grid>

                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Label Text="{Binding HinId}"  
                                           WidthRequest="100"
                                           Margin="2"
                                           FontSize="5"  
                                           Font="Italic"
                                           TextColor="LightBlue"/>

                                    <Label 
                                            Text="{Binding Hin}"  
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           WidthRequest="110"  
                                           FontSize="15"  
                                           TextColor="White"/>
                                </Grid>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

[This image shows before search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOAV2.png)

[After search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nsssp.png)

Comment: What‘s the means of `a positive answer` ? The UI didn't refresh or some other issues? You could provide more details such as the full code or screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some few things i recommend to check why it is not expanding
1. If the list gets filled up with items
2. The layout, what are listview's height/width configs, if placed inside a Layout such as a Grid, what are its height/width configs.